# Laravel - storing in two tables as a transaction

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to save two related models (person & phone number) in two separate tables as a transaction so that if the person insert fails the phone number is not stored.

I tried the DB transaction facade but the models are not available to the closure due to variable scope.

I get the error message:

> Undefined variable: newPerson

I tried adding them as parameters to the closure but it also did not work.

When I perform the two save operations outside the DB Transaction, it works correctly.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $newPerson = new Person;
       $newPerson->name_en = 'New Guy';
       $newPerson->salutation_id = '1';
       $newPerson->gender = '1';
       $newPerson->created_by = '1';

       $phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber;
       $phoneNumber->country_id = '1';
       $phoneNumber->phone_number = '055512345';
       $phoneNumber->phoneType_id = '5';
       $phoneNumber->created_by = '5';

   DB::transaction(function () {
       $newPerson->save();
       $this->$newPerson->phoneNumbers()->save($phoneNumber);
    });



}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use the 'use' keyword.

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($newPerson, $phoneNumber ) {
        $newPerson->save();
        $newPerson->phoneNumbers()->save($phoneNumber);
        });
```